# The imageField doesnt upload images django

Tags: python, django, imagefield

I am trying to upload pictures from an `imageField`, but it doesn't upload anything when I try.

**models.py**

```py
    def upload_location(instance, filename):
        return "uploads/%s/img/%s/" % (instance.id, filename)

    class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        ...
        width_field      = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        height_field     = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        photo    = models.ImageField(
                                            upload_to=upload_location,
                                            null=True, blank=True, 
                                            width_field="width_field", 
                                            height_field="height_field"
                                        )

        USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

        objects = UserManager()
```

**forms.py**

```py
    class UserConfigurationForm(UserChangeForm):

        class Meta:
            model=CustomUser
            fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 
                'direction', 'password', 'photo',)
```

**views.py**

```py
    def configuration(request):

        categoria = Clasificacion.objects.filter(existencia=True)
        templates = Templates.objects.get(isSelected=True)
        if request.method == 'GET':
            form = UserConfigurationForm(instance=request.user)
        else:
            form = UserConfigurationForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            return redirect('myuser:myuser')
        return render(request, 'myuser/configuration.html', {'form': form, 'categoria':categoria,'templates':templates})
```

**template**

```
    <form method="post" action='' enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {%csrf_token%}
                    <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                   <strong>{{form.photo}}</strong></div>
                   <!--FIRST NAME-->
                      <label for="first_name">Nombre</label>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input class= "form-control" type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="20"  value="{{user.first_name}}" required>
                      </div>

                      <label for="last_name">Apellidos</label>
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="last_name" value="{{user.last_name}}">
                      </div>

            <!--Username and email is same in this case-->
                    <label for="last_name">Correo electrónico</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input class= "form-control" type="email" name="email" value="{{user.email}}" required>
                    </div>

            <!--Phone number-->
                    <label for="phone_number">Teléfono</label>        
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input class= "form-control" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" name="phone_number" placeholder="Formato ejem: 0414-685-4716" value="{{user.phone_number}}"required>
                    </div>

            <!--Direction-->
                    <label for="direction">Dirección</label>        
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <textarea id="direction" class= "form-control"  rows="6" name="direction" 
                      value="{{user.direction}}" required>{{user.direction}}</textarea>
                    </div>

            <!--SUBMIT-->
                      <div class="form-group">
                           <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <br>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Guardar cambios</button>
                      </div>
                </form>
```

I did it before but I don't know what is causing this. The other fields are working fine, I just have the problem with the photo. I put the `enctype`, and the `request.FILES` but it doesn't work.

Hope you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Where is the `<input type="file">` element here?

Comment: The file will be uploaded to your `media` folder.  How do you have `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` defined?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The <input type="file"> is in this case the <strong>{{form.photo}}</strong></div> i used that instead of that input..

Comment: @DanSwain i dont use the MEDIA_ROOT because of the function "upload_location" as you can see in the models.py, i have used this way before, but i dont what im doing wrong now.. :/

Comment: Whether you are setting `upload_to` to some string value or using a callable, you still have to define MEDIA_ROOT.  Look at the note in the function `user_directory_path()` in this example:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to